# Replacing mac's login window

Tags: macos, cocoa, authentication, authorization

To customize the login window on Mac OS X you can make an authorization plugin, which implements a mechanism that you can add to the authorization database (in the system.login.console right).

How can we *replace* the login window? If I remove most of the mechanisms from my authorization database and only leave my authorization plugin mechanism (a custom login window) and a few others, then my mac either crashes or it doesn't allow authentication anymore, whatever the password.

Is it possible to truly replace the standard Mac login with a novel one? Eg. a fingerprint mechanism? Hacks are appreciated too.